# What is the way to kill an executing procedure?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am using Oracle sql developer. I have a procedure involving MINUS statement between two tables (table 1 and table 2). The table 1 has more than a million rows data. In this situation, when I am trying to execute it, it returns nothing but is in executing stage.

Meanwhile, I need to truncate this table data. But, when doing this, I got a resource busy error. How to terminate the executing stored procedure and how to do truncate operation meanwhile?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You do not kill a **procedure**, you kill a **session**.

Before killing the session, you might want to know that **readers do not block writers and vice-versa**. So, if you want to **select/project** the rows from the table being modified, you could always do it.

1. **Identify the session:**

```
SELECT s.sid,
       s.serial#,
       p.spid,
       s.username,
       s.program
FROM   v$session s
       JOIN v$process p ON p.addr = s.paddr
WHERE  s.type != 'BACKGROUND';
```

2. **Kill the session:**

```
ALTER SYSTEM KILL SESSION 'sid,serial#';
```

The `KILL SESSION` command doesn't actually kill the session. It merely asks the session to kill itself. In some situations, like waiting for a reply from a remote database or rolling back transactions, the session will not kill itself immediately and will wait for the current operation to complete. In these cases the session will have a status of "marked for kill". It will then be killed as soon as possible.

In addition to the syntax described above, you can add the **IMMEDIATE** clause.

```
ALTER SYSTEM KILL SESSION 'sid,serial#' IMMEDIATE;
```

This does not affect the work performed by the command, but it returns control back to the current session immediately, rather than waiting for confirmation of the kill.

Read this [article](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/killing-oracle-sessions) for more details.

Comment: When I am trying to view the v$session table, I am getting "Table or view does not found" error;

Comment: It means the user you logged into does not have the privilege to access the view. Try with SYSTEM user or a user you use for DBA tasks.

Comment: @Kalyan, of course, your connected DB user doesn't have the privilege to query the `v$session` view. Nor will it, most probably, have the privilege to kill a session.