# drop package body stay executing and cant do it

Tags: oracle, function, package, procedure

In a package body, a code was added by mistake, and even though the package is compiled, the function cannot be used and remains in the executing.

this is code:

```
if admtrans.code_total(codes,datec,102) = 1 then 
        return  null;
            end if;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/arr5y.png)

The added code is in the picture

and my function that stay on executing

Comment: Is the package dropped or compiled? Your title doesn't correspond to the description

Answer (score 1):

If you have the package body:

```sql
CREATE PACKAGE BODY admtrans AS
  FUNCTION code_total(
    codes IN VARCHAR2,
    datec IN DATE,
    value IN VARCHAR2
  ) RETURN NUMBER
  IS
  BEGIN
    if admtrans.code_total(codes,datec,102) = 1 then 
      return  null;
    end if;
  END;
END;
/
```

Then when you call it, the function will call itself and go into an infinite loop.

Either:

1. From the client, cancel the request; or
2. From the server, [kill the client's session](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33888764/1509264).

Once you have stopped it running then edit the package source and recompile so that it does not enter an infinite loop.